# Solvability Condition of a Linear Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is $Ax=B$ only solvable if and only if the last $m-r$ equations reduces to $ 0 = 0$? Why can't each row be independent of each other and still be solvable? r = rank, m = rows. Also how does this relate to $B$ being in $C(A)$. Why is B only in the column space if one row is a combination of the others? Isn't that what the initial solvability condition is stating? Picture added of where confusion is arising. How does does the last paragraph conditions relate? **Why must there be a row that is a combination of the other rows for there to be a solution?**

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that even for singular matrices the system is still solvable if $b\in\mathcal{R}(A)$.

Comment: Changed what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: What are $m$ and $r$?

Comment: Is the matrix supposed to be square? If so, then then it would be vice versa: The system is only solvable for all $B$ if $m=r$.
Note that $C(A)$ is the space spanned by the columns of $A$, i.e. the set $\{Ax:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$, so the system is clearly not solvable if $b\ne C(A)$.

Comment: Updated Again...

Answer (score 0):

Say $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Then $\mathbb{R}^m=\mathcal{N}(A^T)\oplus\mathcal{C}(A)$. Thus, $Ax=b$ is solvable iff $b\in\mathcal{C}(A)$, i.e., iff $b\perp\mathcal{N}(A^T)$. Since the third row of $A$ is the sum of the first two, it is clear that $(1,1,-1)^T\in\mathcal{N}(A^T)$, and since $A$ has rank two, we have in fact that $\mathcal{N}(A^T)=\text{span}\{(1,1,-1)^T\}$. Hence $b\perp\mathcal{N}(A^T)$ iff $(1,1,-1)^T\cdot b=0$, i.e., iff $b_1+b_2-b_3=0$ as stated in the text you quoted.

EDIT: Note that the entries of $b$ might have to fulfill a different relation if the matrix $A$ had different entries.

EDIT 2: $\mathcal{N}(A^T)$ denotes the null space of $A^T$, and the fundamental theorem of linear algebra says that $\mathbb{R}^m=\mathcal{N}(A^T)\oplus\mathcal{C}(A)$, i.e., that every $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ can uniquely be decomposed into $x=x_C+x_N$, where $x_C\in\mathcal{C}(A)$, $x_N\in\mathcal{N}(A^T)$, and $x_C\perp x_N$.